# Are time-based triggers always active?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use an apps script to process incoming messages to my gmail account (a filter won't work in this particular case).  I've created have a time-based trigger that runs every 5 minutes to perform the processing.

My question is whether the time-based trigger is always active?  Do I need to be logged in to Gmail, for example, for the trigger to be run?  Or will it always run independent of whether I'm logged in to a Google service?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to be logged in, or have GMail open.  The trigger is always monitoring for it's particular event, unless it's deleted.  However, there is something that could stop the trigger from running, and that is a quota limit.  Especially for a trigger that is running every 5 minutes, you are probably hitting some kind of quota limit once a day.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy.  I found the list of quotas here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).  Will look to in the script logs to see whether I'm hitting the limits.

Comment: The script that runs every 5 minutes sounds like an overkill. If you plan to execute other scripts, you are probably going to hit that quota limit very soon

Comment: FWIW I've worked on solutions where a Gmail filter selectively forwards emails to a service which triggers a webhook. Depending on what your intended outcome is (The webhook could as easily trigger an apps script), this may be preferable as it is based on actually receiving emails rather than regular polling.

Comment: @Jonathon, thanks.  Sounds like a more elegant solution than polling.  I will check it out.